# how make like Document-centric apps android in my app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I want implement app that move between activities in it look like Document-centric apps in android L.

[like this but for my app between activities](http://www.google.com.eg/imgres?imgurl=http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/recent2.jpg&imgrefurl=http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2014/11/android-5-0-lollipop-thoroughly-reviewed/6/&h=2560&w=4350&tbnid=HPO0ZNY_synMgM:&zoom=1&docid=RvkZY190K7kqVM&hl=en&ei=4rq4VKKAPYXbapbqgtAE&tbm=isch&ved=0CCMQMygHMAc)

how can do this? is there library or anything help me?
thank you so much .